# How to get the difference of two querysets in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have to querysets. alllists and subscriptionlists

```
alllists = List.objects.filter(datamode = 'A')
subscriptionlists = Membership.objects.filter(member__id=memberid, datamode='A')
```

I need a queryset called unsubscriptionlist, which possess all records in alllists except the records in subscription lists. How to achieve this?

Comment: The two querysets in your example appear to use different models. They would need to be using the same model for your question to make sense.

Comment: This is a related answer which is much more concise-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867743/how-does-one-find-the-entities-in-a-django-query-set-that-are-not-in-another-spe

Answer (score 37):

Since Django 1.11, QuerySets have a [`difference()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#models) method amongst other new methods:

```
# Capture elements that are in qs_all but not in qs_part
qs_diff = qs_all.difference(qs_part)
```

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45651267/5497962

Comment: How can I do it at Django 1.10?

Comment: This method can't be used with SQLITE, which raises `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.`.

Comment: What if one of the qs is `NoneType`?

Answer (score 22):

You should be able to use the set operation difference to help:

```
set(alllists).difference(set(subscriptionlists))
```

Comment: Way too complicated of a solution when you can simply use `exclude` instead of `filter`

Comment: Yeah its definitely not optimal if the desired result can be obtained with a single queryset, but if for some reason it can't this is a viable solution.

Comment: True. Hadn't considered that. Good information to leave around for those with complicated queryset math going on.

Comment: And another way to do the same thing:

 set(alllists) - set(ssubscriptionlists)

Comment: this is a good solution when using database backends that don't support `queryset.difference(another_queryset)`

Answer (score 11):

Well I see two options here.

## 1. Filter things manually (quite ugly)

```
diff = []
for all in alllists:
    found = False
    for sub in subscriptionlists:
        if sub.id == all.id:
            found = True 
            break
    if not found:
        diff.append(all)
```

## 2. Just make another query

```
diff = List.objects.filter(datamode = 'A').exclude(member__id=memberid, datamode='A')
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
subscriptionlists = Membership.objects.filter(member__id=memberid, datamode='A')
unsubscriptionlists = Membership.objects.exclude(member__id=memberid, datamode='A')
```

The unsubscriptionlists should be the inverse of subscription lists.

Brian's answer will work as well, though set() will most likely evaluate the query and will take a performance hit in evaluating both sets into memory. This method will keep the lazy initialization until you need the data.

Comment: `unsubscriptionlists = Membership.objects.exclude(member__id=memberid, datamode='A')` should be: `unsubscriptionlists = Membership.objects.filter(datamode='A').exclude(member__id=memberid)`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's searching for a way to do symmetric difference, such operator is not available in Django.

That said, it's not that hard to implement it using `difference` and `union`, and it'll all be done in a single query:

```py
q1.difference(q2).union(q2.difference(q1))
```