# How does one find the entities in a Django query set that are not in another specified query set?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using Django to develop a course registration site for an educational institution.

Suppose I have two Django query sets, one that comprises of courses that occupy session 1 (set A) and one that comprises of courses in session 2 (set B):

```
A = session1.courses.all()
B = session2.courses.all()
```

There is much overlap between these two query sets.

What is an efficient way to obtain the set of courses within set B, but not in set A?

I believe this is equivalent to taking out the intersection of the two sets from set B.

Thank you!

Comment: Starting from version 1.11, django query sets have a builtin difference method. I have added it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`A.exclude(pk__in = B)` should work

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [version 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#difference), django query sets have a builtin difference method.

```
   C = A.difference(B) #A-B
```

See my [blog post](http://technowhisp.com/2017/08/08/django/django-orm-union-intersection-and-difference/) on this for more detailed use cases.